# Use a DAO for reading CSV files?

Tags: java, csv, dao

Is it an acceptable practise to use a DAO pattern to access CSV files?

I'm asking because I'd usually have a utility method to read a CSV. Having a DAO would sort of make sense though if core logic is to be completely separated from any source of data.

Comment: Why not? IMHO, Data Access Object could access any sort of repository behind the interface, not only databases.

Comment: Oh yeah  - I do it all the time. DAO does not necessarily mean database  - it can be flat file, CSV, XML, etc.

Answer (score 3):

[`DAO`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) is a common way to interface with a repository, or backing story of any kind. It's not such much of a design pattern as a means to interface a repository typically with read and store functionality.

If you program against an interface you can easily make an implementation which interfaces a filesystem of CSV files as you proposed. However if you're just going to make a CSV reader it would probably make more sence to provide a `CSV Parser` or some kind of `marshalling` or `serialization` abstraction.